# SQL parsing fails, not sure what the issue is?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

This parses fine:

```
MERGE INTO SECURE_GROUPS USING
    (SELECT :P94_NAME name FROM dual) data
ON (data.name = PEOPLE.PERSON_NAME)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (PERSON_NAME) VALUES (data.name);
```

This fails:

```
 MERGE INTO SECURE_GROUPS USING
        (SELECT :P94_NAME name, :P94_NUMBER num FROM dual) data
    ON (data.name = PEOPLE.PERSON_NAME)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_NUMBER) VALUES (data.name, data.num);
```

The error message is:

1 error has occurred
ORA-06550: line 10, column 51: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ORA-06550: line 9, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: People...stop just rating this question...can someone actually answer? Thanks.

Comment: What is PEOPLE.PERSON_NAME? Is that like a package variable or something? This works for me: MERGE INTO SECURE_GROUPS USING
        (SELECT 'asdsad' name, 232 num FROM dual) data
    ON (data.name = 'as')
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_NUMBER) VALUES (data.name, data.num). Does that work for you?

Comment: PEOPLE.PERSON_NAME People is table...PERSON_NAME is the column

Comment: @antonpug, it is just possible that those people rating the question might not know the answer but think it is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with using PEOPLE.PERSON_NAME like you are, without a select. Try doing it like this:

```
MERGE INTO SECURE_GROUPS
    USING (
        select :P94_NAME name, :P94_NUMBER num from dual
    ) data
    ON (data.name in (select PERSON_NAME from PEOPLE))
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_NUMBER) VALUES (data.name, data.num)
```

Comment: For me, I get the exact same message for both. Namely: ORA-00904: "PEOPLE"."PERSON_NAME": invalid identifier, which is why I asked if that was supposed to be a package variable.